# bottom right, rotated text

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which comes close to what I want but it doesn't sit exactly bottom right.

```css
#top-btn a {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 500;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div id='top-btn'>
  <a href="..." onclick="...">Back Up</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the padding?

Comment: Why do you put `transform-origin` as `bottom left`?

Comment: @ChrisHappy yes, there is `transform-origin: bottom left;` for `#top-btn a`

Comment: no need for the transform origin

Comment: I tried bottom left, but it didn't go to the right edge, Not sure why I need to negative margin as a lot of people are suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons that `<a>` does not sit exactly bottom right:

1. `height` and `padding` is not necessary. It only expand the size of `<a>` after rotation and bring problems.
2. I can understand why you define `transform-origin` as `bottom left` now -- without it, part of `<a>` would be invisible. However, this setting leaves blank area at the right side of `<a>` -- the width of the blank area is exactly the origin width of `<a>`. This is why @DDan and @Zhenya Telegin's answer uses negative `margin-right` to solve the problem. But as the `margin-right` value is a fixed number, it only works for "Back Up".

If the bottom-right text is dynamic, the `margin-right` value should be dynamic too. Here is a solution with JavaScript:

```js
var ele = $('#top-btn a');
ele.css('margin-right', -ele.width()+'px');
```

```css
#top-btn a {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 500;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='top-btn'>
   <a href="..." onclick="...">Back Up</a>
</div>
```

I tried several pure CSS solutions but all failed, looking forward if someone solve this problem with pure CSS.

Comment: Seems like a solid solution, 2 questions though. Do I put that in the head tags or footer (if it matters) and 2. I need the padding to make the button hit box bigger, make it easier to click the button rather than the text

Comment: @user3550879 For your questions: 1. you can put JavaScript code near the end of `</body>` tag, which is a common practice. 2. If padding is needed for user experience, then it is necessary. Maybe you can give it a background color to make things feel better :)

Comment: Is there a way to include padding and still keep it bottom right

Comment: Yes, you can just define `padding-left` & `padding-top`, and leave `padding-bottom` & `padding-right` to 0.

Comment: ok perfect, but can I push it off the bottom right so it looks like there's padding around it?

Comment: hmmm, don't know what exactly you want. Do you want to have padding on right&bottom side, and meanwhile keep `<a>` bottom right? I can't imagine the final result. Maybe you can attach some pictures?

Comment: I just want the button to have a 25px (roughly) padding all around the button so that it's easier to click on. I want the edge of that 25px border to be bottom right. If it's right against the edge, the scrollbar will interfere with it

Comment: @user3550879 if you need padding, you can use `ele.innerWidth()` instead of `ele.width()`. I made an example: https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/gx7y3ymL/  is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think the rotate cause problem... You can remove `height: 40px;` and add negative margin right
`margin-right: -55px;`

```css
#top-btn a {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 500;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  margin-right: -55px;
}
```

```html
<div id='top-btn'>
  <a href="..." onclick="...">Back Up</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two tricks you can do here:

- Leave out `transform-origin`
- You can set negative right margin to move it more to the side. See `margin-right` in css.

```css
#top-btn a {
  direction: rtl;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 500;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  margin-right: -40px; 
}
```

```html
<div id='top-btn'>
  <a href="..." onclick="...">Back Up</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working like you described in the following snippet. Like the others said the `height` thing is problematic. However, I didn't bother messing with a right margin but instead solved it with `transform-origin` percent values.

```css
#top-btn a {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 500;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id='top-btn'>
  <a href="..." onclick="...">Back Up</a>
</div>
```

## Update

I've found an even better solution that works for text of any length. Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalenconner/5kpcz0x0/) for the better solution.

Comment: You have it fixed and absolute positioned?

Comment: @user3550879 haha whoops. Was playing around with different solutions and forgot to remove that before I posted lol. Thanks for pointing it out; I've edited it out of my answer.

Comment: Ok perfect lol. My only concern with doing margins this way is if the text changes that would change how close the text is to the edge. The smaller the content, the closer to the edge

Comment: @user3550879 I've updated my answer with an even better solution.